# JSP for a small project

Tags: jsp

I would like to organize my own web site. This means that I can spend up to $30 for hosting. What about visitors? Let us be hoping fo up to 3000 per day in half a year.

This is my first experience in web. The site will contain articles, a forum and a wiki.
I have to choose a language and a web framework. Somehow I am afraid of dynamic languages (like Python or Ruby). I would gladly use Java. But as far as I have heard, Java is not a suitable solution for a shared hosting. Maybe I’m lack behind the time.
Well, let us start with static and dynamic typing. This is what troubles me most. Dynamic typing is not that safe. They say you can use testing. Well, yes. But this means that the speed of development will be not much higher. Then there is a maintainability problem. I think it is easier to maintain a project in Java. Of course, it is much easier to make a simple site in a script language. But it is harder to make a robust and viable one.
They say that Java devours resources and needs restarting of the virtual machines. Is it a problem nowadays?

They say that Java is for enterprise level only. But on the other hand any web project is at enterprise level. 
Then. Will I be able to find any ready made wiki  module in case of JSF? And a forum as well? Could you show me examples of such sites?

I just don’t understand why most web projects are written in script languages. Simplicity of those languages is somehow a weak argument as compared to the benefits of static typing.
Then there is a problem of community. Communities in PHP, Ruby or Python are huge. But documentation is not that good. And good documentation may often be better than any community.

If you work in a bank, it is strange that you should constantly google for somebody else’s code or seek for advice.

Well, I just wanted to hear your opinion. If you say that JSP is not for you, I’ll be happy with Python or something.

Comment: Wait! PHP, Ruby or Python... documentation is not that good ? Are you sure ?

Comment: This question does not fit on SO. Please Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: The documentation for PHP is the best of them. Python's documentation is cryptic. Rubi is notorious for it's bad docs. To tell notning (!) about frameworkds in these languages. They say Django's documentation is good. But what is Django's team against Oracle's one.